# Pearson Algorithm from Programming Collective Intelligence still not working

Tags: python, algorithm, pearson

I ran the code to calculate the Pearson Correlation Coefficient and the function (pasted below) stubbornly returns a 0.

In line with earlier suggestions on this issue here on SO (see #1, #2 below), I did make sure that the function is able to perform floating point calculations but that hasn't helped. I would appreciate some guidance with this.

```
    from __future__ import division
    from math import sqrt

    def sim_pearson(prefs,p1,p2):
    # Get the list of mutually rated items
       si={}
       for item in prefs[p1]:
          if item in prefs[p2]: si[item]=1


          # Find the number of elements
          n=float(len(si))


          # if they are no ratings in common, return 0
          if n==0: return 0


          # Add up all the preferences
          sum1=float(sum([prefs[p1][it] for it in si]))
          sum2=float(sum([prefs[p2][it] for it in si]))

          # Sum up the squares
          sum1Sq=sum([pow(prefs[p1][it],2) for it in si])
          sum2Sq=sum([pow(prefs[p2][it],2) for it in si])

          # Sum up the products
          pSum=sum([prefs[p1][it]*prefs[p2][it] for it in si])


          # Calculate Pearson score
          num=pSum-(1.0*sum1*sum2/n)
          den=sqrt((sum1Sq-1.0*pow(sum1,2)/n)*(sum2Sq-1.0*pow(sum2,2)/n))
          if den==0: return 0

          r=num/den

          return r
```

My Data Set:

```
 # A dictionary of movie critics and their ratings of a small
 # set of movies

 critics={'Lisa Rose': {'Lady in the Water': 2.5, 'Snakes on a Plane': 3.5,
       'Just My Luck': 3.0, 'Superman Returns': 3.5, 'You, Me and Dupree': 2.5,
       'The Night Listener': 3.0},
     'Gene Seymour': {'Lady in the Water': 3.0, 'Snakes on a Plane': 3.5,
      'Just My Luck': 1.5, 'Superman Returns': 5.0, 'The Night Listener': 3.0,
      'You, Me and Dupree': 3.5},
     'Michael Phillips': {'Lady in the Water': 2.5, 'Snakes on a Plane': 3.0,
      'Superman Returns': 3.5, 'The Night Listener': 4.0},
     'Claudia Puig': {'Snakes on a Plane': 3.5, 'Just My Luck': 3.0,
      'The Night Listener': 4.5, 'Superman Returns': 4.0,
      'You, Me and Dupree': 2.5},
     'Mick LaSalle': {'Lady in the Water': 3.0, 'Snakes on a Plane': 4.0,
      'Just My Luck': 2.0, 'Superman Returns': 3.0, 'The Night Listener': 3.0,
      'You, Me and Dupree': 2.0},
     'Jack Matthews': {'Lady in the Water': 3.0, 'Snakes on a Plane': 4.0,
      'The Night Listener': 3.0, 'Superman Returns': 5.0, 'You, Me and Dupree': 3.5},
     'Toby': {'Snakes on a Plane':4.5,'You, Me and Dupree':1.0,'Superman Returns':4.0}}
```

Other Similar Questions:

- Link #1:
  [What is wrong with this python function from "Programming Collective Intelligence"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423525/what-is-wrong-with-this-python-function-from-programming-collective-intelligenc)
- Link #2:
  [What is wrong with the pearson algorithm from “Programming Collective Intelligence”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778411/what-is-wrong-with-the-pearson-algorithm-from-programming-collective-intelligen)

Comment: Please include a sample data set.  Presumably data sets exist for which the result should be zero.

Comment: You also might like to include links to the previous questions, to give more detailed context.

Comment: Yes, please provide the `prefs` that are defined in the `for` loop in line 3. If they are null, or if prefs[p1] is null, specifically, then `len(si)` will be 0 and hence n will be 0 as well.

Comment: I found [this function](http://pastebin.com/k98e8pr1) in a statistics script I wrote for a class. It takes in a list of two-tuples and uses some formula I found online somewhere, and it gave me the right answer when I used it for homework. It might be useful to look at.

Comment: @BrianCain Just updated my post to include the data set.

Comment: @rofls         I am new to Python programming. How do I provide those prefs defined in the for loop?

Comment: @user1828663, welcome to Python, and SO. BrianCain did that for you!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to everyone's help in the comments I've identified the problem. Just kidding. There were tons of problems. In the end, I noticed the for loop wasn't doubled up (in line 6) and it needed to be. One stage before the end, I frantically surrounded everything in `float`, sorry. Anyway, you want floats. Before that, there was the fact that he wasn't referencing the `keys()` for the critics, which he needed to be. Also, the pearson coefficient was calculated incorrectly, so much so that it required a mathematician to fix it (I have a BA in math). Now his tested example for Gene Seymour and Lisa Rose works correctly. Anyway, save this as `pearson.py`, or something:

```
from __future__ import division
from math import sqrt

def sim_pearson(prefs,p1,p2):
# Get the list of mutually rated items
   si={}
   for item in prefs[p1].keys():
      for item in prefs[p2].keys():
         if item in prefs[p2].keys():
            si[item]=1


      # Find the number of elements
      n=float(len(si))


      # if they are no ratings in common, return 0
      if n==0:
         print 'n=0'
         return 0


      # Add up all the preferences
      sum1=float(sum([prefs[p1][it] for it in si.keys()]))
      sum2=float(sum([prefs[p2][it] for it in si.keys()]))
      print 'sum1=', sum1, 'sum2=', sum2
      # Sum up the squares
      sum1Sq=float(sum([pow(prefs[p1][it],2) for it in si.keys()]))
      sum2Sq=float(sum([pow(prefs[p2][it],2) for it in si.keys()]))
      print 'sum1s=', sum1Sq, 'sum2s=', sum2Sq
      # Sum up the products
      pSum=float(sum([prefs[p1][it]*prefs[p2][it] for it in si.keys()]))


      # Calculate Pearson score
      num=(pSum/n)-(1.0*sum1*sum2/pow(n,2))
      den=sqrt(((sum1Sq/n)-float(pow(sum1,2))/float(pow(n,2)))*((sum2Sq/n)-float(pow(sum2,2))/float(pow(n,2))))
      if den==0:
         print 'den=0'
         return 0

      r=num/den

      return r

critics={'Lisa Rose': {'Lady in the Water': 2.5, 'Snakes on a Plane': 3.5,
   'Just My Luck': 3.0, 'Superman Returns': 3.5, 'You, Me and Dupree': 2.5,
   'The Night Listener': 3.0},
 'Gene Seymour': {'Lady in the Water': 3.0, 'Snakes on a Plane': 3.5,
  'Just My Luck': 1.5, 'Superman Returns': 5.0, 'The Night Listener': 3.0,
  'You, Me and Dupree': 3.5},
 'Michael Phillips': {'Lady in the Water': 2.5, 'Snakes on a Plane': 3.0,
  'Superman Returns': 3.5, 'The Night Listener': 4.0},
 'Claudia Puig': {'Snakes on a Plane': 3.5, 'Just My Luck': 3.0,
  'The Night Listener': 4.5, 'Superman Returns': 4.0,
                                                                                                                                                             1,1
```

Then, type:

```
import pearson
pearson.sim_pearson(pearson.critics, pearson.critics.keys()[1], pearson.critics.keys()[2])
```

or simply:

```
import pearson
pearson.sim_pearson(pearson.critics, 'Lisa Rose', 'Gene Seymour')
```

Let me know if you have any problems getting it to work. I left the `print` statements that I used to troubleshoot it, just so you can see how I solved it, but they're obviously not needed.

If you run into anymore problems in this book and you can't fix them, with SO's help that is, email me: raphael[at]postacle.com, and I should be able to get back to you. I downloaded it too a while ago, just a little lazy ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I had an issue with your code where it worked for the Lisa Rose/Gene Seymour combo but it still gave me error msgs for other combos. The error messages looked like "KeyError: 'Lady in the Water'" for my input of "pearson.sim_pearson(pearson.critics, 'Toby', 'Gene Seymour')". That being said, after re-writing the denominator part in another way and fixing the for-loop issue, things started running a lot more smoothly. Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 0):

@rofls was right -

- For Loop: My *for-loop* was an issue. Floats: Some of the terms needed to be converted to a float type from the int type.
- **Keys**: This is something I definitely missed the first time around and @rofls caught.
- Pearson Coefficient: I tightened the denominator component of the Pearson coefficient to line it with the expression on the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_productmoment_correlation_coefficient) page; it's the last expression under the *Mathematical Properties* section.

The code works now. I tried it for different combinations of the inputs.

```
    from __future__ import division
    from math import sqrt

    def sim_pearson(prefs,p1,p2):
    # Get the list of mutually rated items
       si={}
       for item in prefs[p1].keys():
           if item in prefs[p2].keys():
               print 'item=', item
               si[item]=1

       # Find the number of elements
       n=float(len(si))
       print 'n=', n

       # if they are no ratings in common, return 0
       if n==0:
           print 'n=0'
           return 0

       # Add up all the preferences
       sum1=float(sum([prefs[p1][it] for it in si.keys()]))
       sum2=float(sum([prefs[p2][it] for it in si.keys()]))
       print 'sum1=', sum1, 'sum2=', sum2

       # Sum up the squares
       sum1Sq=float(sum([pow(prefs[p1][it],2) for it in si.keys()]))
       sum2Sq=float(sum([pow(prefs[p2][it],2) for it in si.keys()]))
       print 'sum1s=', sum1Sq, 'sum2s=', sum2Sq

       # Sum up the products
       pSum=float(sum([prefs[p1][it]*prefs[p2][it] for it in si.keys()]))
       print 'pSum=', pSum

       # Calculate Pearson score
       num=(n*pSum)-(1.0*sum1*sum2)
       print 'num=', num
       den1=sqrt((n*sum1Sq)-float(pow(sum1,2)))
       print 'den1=', den1
       den2=sqrt((n*sum2Sq)-float(pow(sum2,2)))
       print 'den2=', den2
       den=1.0*den1*den2

      if den==0:
           print 'den=0'
           return 0

       r=num/den
       return r

    critics={'Lisa Rose': {'Lady in the Water': 2.5, 'Snakes on a Plane': 3.5,
          'Just My Luck': 3.0, 'Superman Returns': 3.5, 'You, Me and Dupree': 2.5,
          'The Night Listener': 3.0},
         'Gene Seymour': {'Lady in the Water': 3.0, 'Snakes on a Plane': 3.5,
          'Just My Luck': 1.5, 'Superman Returns': 5.0, 'The Night Listener': 3.0,
          'You, Me and Dupree': 3.5},
         'Michael Phillips': {'Lady in the Water': 2.5, 'Snakes on a Plane': 3.0,
          'Superman Returns': 3.5, 'The Night Listener': 4.0},
         'Claudia Puig': {'Snakes on a Plane': 3.5, 'Just My Luck': 3.0,
          'The Night Listener': 4.5, 'Superman Returns': 4.0,
          'You, Me and Dupree': 2.5},
         'Mick LaSalle': {'Lady in the Water': 3.0, 'Snakes on a Plane': 4.0,
          'Just My Luck': 2.0, 'Superman Returns': 3.0, 'The Night Listener': 3.0,
          'You, Me and Dupree': 2.0},
         'Jack Matthews': {'Lady in the Water': 3.0, 'Snakes on a Plane': 4.0,
          'The Night Listener': 3.0, 'Superman Returns': 5.0, 'You, Me and Dupree': 3.5},
         'Toby': {'Snakes on a Plane':4.5,'You, Me and Dupree':1.0,'Superman Returns':4.0}}

    # Done
```